# Always show desktop version

Tags: html, mobile, desktop

How always, show the desktop version of the site so that the selects always look like on the desktop, now they look like this

[image]

It is necessary that it would always be like on a desktop

[image]

How to always show the desktop version on mobile phones?

Comment: Whats the query here?

Comment: How to always show the desktop version on mobile phones?

Comment: Select boxes are generated by the browser so you would need to implement a select box replacement mechanism if you want a consistent look across a variety of browsers/platforms.

Comment: Hidden Hobbes then without replacing the selects for another component, the browser will always show the mobile version on mobile phones? And I can not force in html that the desktop version would be shown? For example with viewport?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then yes, the select box options will always be governed by the browser/platform you are on, styling options are limited.